# How to transition along a circular path with d3?

Tags: d3.js

I have an element (a circle but it shouldn't matter) selected with d3. I would like it to move in a clockwise circle returning to its original position.

Reading through the [transition](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions) docs I can understand how to transition attributes of the element on a linear path, but how would I do it on a circular path? Would I have to code a custom transition using something like `attrTween` or is there something built in?

Comment: Nothing built-in, but relatively easy to do. See [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @LarsKotthoff's comment I was able to figure it out fairly simple. In coffeescript:

```
    do rotateClockwise = ->
        element
            .transition()
            .attrTween 'cx', -> (t) -> initial[0] + 10 * Math.cos (2*Math.PI * t)                
            .attrTween 'cy', -> (t) -> initial[1] + 10 * Math.sin (2*Math.PI * t)                
            .duration 4000
            .ease 'linear'
            .each 'end', rotateClockwise
```

where `10` is the radius of the circular path and `initial` is the initial starting location